# Dynamically grouping html elements in side of a parent div class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to sort each "panel" into one div each depending on what class my element has, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've gotten to the point of where I'm dynamically setting the class tag for each panel, but I can't figure out how to group them into one div per dynamic class that I set based off my json array element "PressNo".

## JS

```
//this is where I set the panel data

function Panel(opts) {
  
  return ['<div class="', opts.classcontrol, '">',
          '<div class="panel">',
          '  <div class="panel-heading">',
          '    <h4>',
          '     <span class="status"><b class="fa fa-', opts.icon, '"></b></span>',
          '     <span class="name">', Utils.escapeHtml(opts.title), '</span>',
          '    </h4>',
          '  </div>',
          '  <div class="panel-body">',
          (opts.trustedBody || Utils.escapeHtml(opts.body)),
          '  </div>',
          '</div></div>'].join('');

}

// get json data for panel 

function ConfigurationController(element) {
  if ( !element ) { throw new Error('Cannot create ConfigurationController: Element Required');}
  var self = this,
    _limit = 2,
    apiUrl = "http://localhost:58938/api/ShopViewDisplay/PLTO/PLTO/10";

  // Expose Public method(s)
  this.load = load;
  //this.render = render;

  function load() {
    reset()
    $.ajax({

        url : apiUrl,
        type : 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(data) {              
                    data.map(renderItem, function(el) {
                    element.append(el);
        });
        },  
        error : function(request,error)
        {
            alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
  }
  
  // this renders each item 

  function renderItem(obj, index, list) {
    var callback = typeof this === 'function' ? this : false;
    // This could use document create fragment, possible speed boost
    // 20% of the time, pick random status icon, in all other cases pick the 'good' check icon.
    
                function renderItem(obj) {
                    var callback = typeof this === 'function' ? this : false;
        
                    var statusIcon = "fire";
                    var itemPanel = Panel({
                        icon: statusIcon,
                        title: obj.WorkOrderNumber,
                        classcontrol: obj.PressNo,
                        trustedBody: [
                            '    <div class="PressNo"><b></b> Machine:  <br>', Utils.escapeHtml(obj.PressNo), '</br></div>',
                            '    <br>                                                                   ',
                            '    <div class="Priority"><b></b> Priority:  <br>', Utils.escapeHtml(obj.Priority),
                            '</br></div>',
                            '    <br>                                                                   ',
                            '    <div class="PartNo"><b></b> Part:  <br>', Utils.escapeHtml(obj.Part), '</br></div>',
                            '    <br>                                                                   ',
                            '    <div class="Material"><b></b> Material: <br>', Utils.escapeHtml(obj.PartDesc), '</br></div>',
                            '    <br>                                                                   ',
                            '    <div class="Setup"><b></b> Setup(E/A): <br>',
                            Utils.escapeHtml(obj.EstActSetupHrs).replace('\r\n', ' / '), '</br></div>',
                            '    <br>                                                                   ',
                            '    <div class="Run"><b></b> Run (E/A): <br>',
                            Utils.escapeHtml(obj.EstActRunHrs).replace('\r\n', ' / '), '</br></div>',
                            '    <br>                                                                   ',
                            '    <div class="Qty"><b></b> Qty: <br>',
                            Utils.escapeHtml(obj.CalEndCompleteQty).replace('\r\n', ' / '), ' </br></div>'
                        ].join('\n')
                    });
    
                    itemPanel = $(itemPanel);
    
        myFunction();

    return (typeof(callback) === 'function' ? callback(itemPanel) : itemPanel);}
```

## HTML

## Here is where I append the panels

```
<body>
<div id="configurationList">
    <h2>
        <b class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></b>
        <i>Loading, please wait...</i>
    </h2>
</div>
</body>
```

Example of what I would like to see happen:

```
 <div class="5-1">
    panel 1 - class="panel" - I have PressNo 5-1
    panel 6 - class="panel" - I have PressNo 5-1
 </div>

 <div class="7">
    panel 2 - class="panel" - I have PressNo 7
    panel 8 - class="panel" - I have PressNo 7
 </div>

 <div class="9-3">
    panel 9 - class="panel" - I have PressNo 9-3
    panel 10 - class="panel" - I have PressNo 9-3
 </div>
```

This is what it looks like now

[image]

This is what I would like it to look like

[image]

## update trying @obscure suggestion/answer

I get the following in my browser console -

```
TypeError: theDiv[0] is undefined
```

When I console log I get the following output (it looks like my data hasn't been loaded yet).

```
console.log(id, document.getElementsByClassName(id));
1 HTMLCollection { length: 0 } index:116:25
```

## Full code

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        'use strict';

        var Utils = {
            escapeHtml: function _escapeHtml(s) { // Prevent code injection and rendering issues
                return String(s).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/</g, '&lt;');
            }
        };

        function Panel(opts) {

            /*return ['<div class="', opts.classcontrol, '">',
                    '<div class="panel">',
                    '  <div class="panel-heading">',
                    '    <h4>',
                    '     <span class="status"><b class="fa fa-', opts.icon, '"></b></span>',
                    '     <span class="name">', Utils.escapeHtml(opts.title), '</span>',
                    '    </h4>',
                    '  </div>',
                    '  <div class="panel-body">',
                    (opts.trustedBody || Utils.escapeHtml(opts.body)),
                    '  </div>',
                    '</div></div>'].join('');
              */
            return ['<div class="', opts.classcontrol, '">',
                '<div class="panel">',
                '  <div class="panel-heading">',
                '    <h4>',
                '     <span class="status"><b class="fa fa-', opts.icon, '"></b></span>',
                '     <span class="name">', Utils.escapeHtml(opts.title), '</span>',
                '    </h4>',
                '  </div>',
                '  <div class="panel-body">',
                (opts.trustedBody || Utils.escapeHtml(opts.body)),
                '  </div>',
                '</div></div>'].join('');
        }

        function ConfigurationController(element) {
            if (!element) {
                throw new Error('Cannot create ConfigurationController: Element Required');
            }
            var self = this,
                apiUrl = "http://pdapi.pennunited.com/api/ShopViewDisplay/" + "@ViewBag.pathProc";
            console.log(apiUrl);

            // Expose Public method(s)
            this.load = load;
            //this.render = render;

            function load() {
                // Attempt ajax call; on fail: use dummy data
                reset();
                $.ajax({
                    url: apiUrl,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        data.map(renderItem,
                            function(el) {
                                element.append(el);
                                
                            });
                    },
                    error: function(request, error) {
                        alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request) + " Error: " + error);
                    }
                });
            }

            function reset() {
                element.children().remove();
                return element;
            }

            function renderItem(obj) {
                var callback = typeof this === 'function' ? this : false;
    
                var statusIcon = "fire";
                var itemPanel = Panel({
                    icon: statusIcon,
                    title: obj.WorkOrderNumber,
                    classcontrol: obj.PressNo,
                    trustedBody: [
                        '    <div class="PressNo"><b></b> Machine:  <br>', Utils.escapeHtml(obj.PressNo), '</br></div>',
                        '    <br>                                                                   ',
                        '    <div class="Priority"><b></b> Priority:  <br>', Utils.escapeHtml(obj.Priority),
                        '</br></div>',
                        '    <br>                                                                   ',
                        '    <div class="PartNo"><b></b> Part:  <br>', Utils.escapeHtml(obj.Part), '</br></div>',
                        '    <br>                                                                   ',
                        '    <div class="Material"><b></b> Material: <br>', Utils.escapeHtml(obj.PartDesc), '</br></div>',
                        '    <br>                                                                   ',
                        '    <div class="Setup"><b></b> Setup(E/A): <br>',
                        Utils.escapeHtml(obj.EstActSetupHrs).replace('\r\n', ' / '), '</br></div>',
                        '    <br>                                                                   ',
                        '    <div class="Run"><b></b> Run (E/A): <br>',
                        Utils.escapeHtml(obj.EstActRunHrs).replace('\r\n', ' / '), '</br></div>',
                        '    <br>                                                                   ',
                        '    <div class="Qty"><b></b> Qty: <br>',
                        Utils.escapeHtml(obj.CalEndCompleteQty).replace('\r\n', ' / '), ' </br></div>'
                    ].join('\n')
                });

                itemPanel = $(itemPanel);

                var id = Utils.escapeHtml(obj.PressNo);
                console.log(id, document.getElementsByClassName(id));
                var theDiv=document.getElementsByClassName(id);
                theDiv[0].appendChild(itemPanel);


                //myFunction();

                return (typeof (callback) === 'function' ? callback(itemPanel) : itemPanel);
            }
        }

        function scroll(speed) {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() }, speed, function() {
                $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
            });

        }


        $(document).ready(function _onLoad() {
            var ctrl = new ConfigurationController($('#configurationList'));
            ctrl.load();

            //ctrl.load();
            //var speed = 15000;
            //scroll(speed)
            //setInterval(function () { scroll(speed) }, speed * 8);
            //setInterval(ctrl.load(), 900000);
        });


    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 82px 0px 0px 0px;
            /* for fixed heading */
            /*padding-top: 67px;*/
        }


        h1 { margin: 4px 2px; }

        h4 { margin: 2px 2px; }

        .page-header-fixed {
            left: 0;
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            top: 0px;
        }

        /* Define a bootstrap-ish minimal style
        ---- 425363 */

        .text-success { color: #94c0e9; }

        .text-info { color: #0071ce; }

        .text-warning { color: #ff8300; }

        .PressNo { color: green; }

        .Priority { color: red; }

        .page-header {
            background: #425363;
            box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90) 5px 1px 4px 0px;
            color: #FFF;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            padding: 6px 10px;
            /*line-height: 48px;*/
            transition: all 0.2s;
        }

        .panel {
            background-color: #FFF;
            border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
            border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
            border-top: none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: #666666;
            font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            line-height: 20px;
            margin: 8px 2px;
            transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
        }

        .panel-heading {
            background-color: #0071ce;
            border-color: #2196F3;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 19px;
            padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
            transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in, color 0.25s ease-in;
        }

        .panel-body {
            padding: 15px;
            transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in, color 0.25s ease-in;
        }

        /*.btn {
          border: none;
          font-family: inherit;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 25px 80px;
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 15px 30px;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          letter-spacing: 1px;
          font-weight: 700;
          outline: none;
          position: relative;
        }*/

        .status .fa {
            font-size: 22px;
            margin: 6px;
        }

        .panel-footer {
            text-align: right;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .panel-footer .fa {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin: 8px;
        }

        .panel .fa { opacity: 1; }

        .panel:hover .panel-heading { background-color: #ff8300; }

        .panel:hover { box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 3px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.8); }

        .panel:hover .fa {
            color: #ff8300;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #FFFFFF;
            transition: all 0.2s ease, font-size 0.2s ease-in;
        }

        .panel:hover .panel-heading .fa { color: #333333; }

        .panel-heading .fa-exclamation-circle { color: yellow; }

        .panel-heading .fa-check { color: #FFF; }

        .panel-heading .fa-fire {
            color: #ff8300;
            font-size: 26px;
        }

        .panel-body b.fa {
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 30px;
        }


        #configurationList {
            -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            justify-content: space-around;
            width: 99%;
        }

        #configurationList .panel {
            display: inline-block;
            min-height: 100px;
            width: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="configurationList">
    <h2>
        <b class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></b>
        <i>Loading, please wait...</i>
    </h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see where you're actually appending the panels to the DOM. Is that piece of code missing? `obj.PressNo` is the Machine ID you want to use?

Comment: Just to be clear: You want to retain the same 2D grid layout for machine parts but you want to group all parts for each separate machine ?

Comment: @obscure I edited my post to include that now.

Comment: @Trunk I would like to group each panels into a machine div from "PressNo"

Comment: @Trunk my example picture at the bottom is what I would like it to look like if their is a better way of doing the panels I'm open suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're generating each container DIV - e.g. class="5.1" with each panel.

```
function Panel(opts) {

  return ['<div class="', opts.classcontrol, '">',
          '<div class="panel">',
          '  <div class="panel-heading">',
          '    <h4>',
          '     <span class="status"><b class="fa fa-', opts.icon, '"></b></span>',
          '     <span class="name">', Utils.escapeHtml(opts.title), '</span>',
          '    </h4>',
          '  </div>',
          '  <div class="panel-body">',
          (opts.trustedBody || Utils.escapeHtml(opts.body)),
          '  </div>',
          '</div></div>'].join('');

}
```

I assume `'<div class="', opts.classcontrol, '">'` is the target div.
Anyway, this means you're generating a new container div each time you generate a new panel. You should make sure that there isn't a div that uses that specific class before you create a new one.

```
function Panel(opts) {
  var theDiv = document.getElementsByClassName(opts.classcontrol);
  var theArray = ['<div class="panel">',
    '  <div class="panel-heading">',
    '    <h4>',
    '     <span class="status"><b class="fa fa-', opts.icon, '"></b></span>',
    '     <span class="name">', Utils.escapeHtml(opts.title), '</span>',
    '    </h4>',
    '  </div>',
    '  <div class="panel-body">',
    (opts.trustedBody || Utils.escapeHtml(opts.body)),
    '  </div>',
    '</div></div>'
  ];
  if (theDiv.length == 0) {
    theArray.splice(0, 0, '<div class="', opts.classcontrol, '">');
    theArray.push("</div>");
  }

  return theArray.join('');
}
```

Inside the function **renderItem()** we need to make this distinction once more.

Right after

```
itemPanel = $(itemPanel);
```

Insert this

```
var theDiv = document.getElementsByClassName(obj.PressNo);
if (theDiv.length == 0) {
  return (typeof(callback) === 'function' ? callback(itemPanel) : itemPanel);
} else {
  theDiv[0].appendChild(itemPanel);
  return undefined;
}
```

and remove

```
return (typeof(callback) === 'function' ? callback(itemPanel) : itemPanel);
```

at the end of that function.

This appends the newly created panel to the corresponding parent div - in case it exists. The `return undefined` is a workaround
for this code inside your **load()** function

```
function(el) {
  element.append(el);

});
```

it would try to append whatever el is to element. Since we might already appended the panel before we need to make sure it won't get appended a second time.
So modify the above to

```
function(el) {
  if (el != undefined) {
    element.append(el);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however, I get a the following error in the web console - TypeError: theDiv[0] is undefined @obscure

Comment: Then try inserting a `console.log(id, document.getElementsByClassName(id));` right after `var id=Utils...` and tell me what you see. I expect the DIVS e.g. `<div class="5-1">` exist yet, does it?

Comment: @obsure It looks like the expected div (ex: class="5-1") doesn't exist yet it only exist after the ------------------------- data.map(renderItem, function(el) {
  element.append(el);
});

Comment: So a call to `ConfigurationController(element)`actually creates one of those class="5-1" Divs?

Comment: Would it help if I posted my entire file ? @obscure

Comment: Ah `'<div class="', opts.classcontrol, '">'` is generating those container divs - I assumed it's the id of a panel itself.

Comment: yes should I do something differently ? - I added my entire file if that helps! @obscure

Comment: I revised my complete answer since it didn't make sense anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the update @obscure - I have another issue now with -- TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node. Is this because its expecting jquery and not vanilla js?